Python Telethon, delays in receiving new messages through update handler
I'm building a python telethon update handler which will read messages from a list of groups which will then send different tickers to my crypto exchange API. The program needs to require the update handler receiving the message miliseconds after it was sent into the channel. However, it's taking at least 20 to 60 seconds for each message to be processed and sent to the handler. Is there any code I can implement to make the update handler push messages through much faster, preferably in milliseconds?
client = TelegramClient('123445.session', '#####', '#####',flood_sleep_threshold=0)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[x[0] for x in idList.items()]))
async def my_event_handler(event):

    nowDate = datetime.now()
    verified, groupVerified,logBookList,queueList, ticker,dateOfMessage,signalled,endOfSignalled,stopReload,priceVerify, includesImage, nonTrade,notVerified,pumpVerified,tickerNotFound,username,newMessage,includesImageTag,startOfTickerFinder,endOfTickerFinder = 0,1,[],[],0,event.message.date,"Message Time: "+str(event.message.date),"Signalled: "+str(datetime.now()),1,0,False,0,0,0,0,event.chat.username,(event.message.message.encode("utf-8")).decode("utf-8"),"","Ticker Finder not used", "Ticker Finder not used"
    global previousMessage,accountsList,offSwitch,previousTickers,switchSelector,groupDict,idList
    if event.photo != None: includesImage,includesImageTag = True,"{INCLUDES IMAGE}"

    userDict = {'username':str(username),
                'switchSelectorNumber':str(groupDict[username][0]),
                'sellLimit':float(groupDict[username][1]),
                'stopLoss':float(groupDict[username][2]),
                'group':str(username),
                'logBookNumber':str(groupDict[username][4]),
                'timeLimit':float(groupDict[username][5]),
                'amountPercentage':float(groupDict[username][6]),
                'timeout': float(groupDict[username][10])
                }

    if nowDate.timestamp() - dateOfMessage.timestamp() > 120:
        #try:
        startOfTickerFinder = "Start of ticker finder: "+str(datetime.now())
        nonTradeTicker = tickerfinder.findticker(newMessage,userDict['username'],previousMessage[userDict['username']],includesImage)
        endOfTickerFinder = "End of ticker finder: "+str(datetime.now())
        #except:
            #nonTradeTicker = (0,0)
        timeFrameList = getTradeInfo(str(userDict['username']))

        stopList = getStopInfo(str(userDict['username']))

I have tried everything with this, including using regex as a filter for the handler, requesting get_input_entity after every iteration of the handler to keep telethon interested in the channels and I have also tried getting most messages from each channel after every iteration. I have searched everywhere, tried everything and nothing is working. If anyone could help, It would be greatly appreciated!

first you could use print() to display current time in different lines - to see which lines take so long. OR maybe problem is slow network and you have to run it on server on internet.

There is some discussion in https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/issues/4345.
